# Comment tooltip: improving wrong answers

Tags: discussion, comments

The tooltip for a question comment reads:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.  Avoid answering questions in comments.

The tooltip for an answer comment reads:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.  Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

The wording of these tooltips makes more sense for computer programming than than it does for politics.

To a commentator favoring one spot on the political spectrum, *"suggest improvements"* often seems to imply, and is therefore inferred to mean, that they should help by extolling the norms and virtues of their preferred spot, or by condemning those spots occupied by that particular question or answer.  Since the commentator is only helping a misguided person who seems lost, such extolling and condemnation often seems, to them, compliant with the "Be Nice" policy.

How does a user "improve" a wrong answer?  Or an answer that seems to them, given their orientation, wrong?  Is the verb *"improve"* ill-suited to political discussion?

Comment: Is there an example of this problem occurring? I haven't interpreted the tool tip that way and it would be enlightening to see how this went.

Comment: @indigochild, Example: often we see comment threads devolve into partisan contrariness, sometimes due to spite, other times owing to a fog of mutually oppositional obliviousness.  The *best* (*i.e.* worst) examples have probably been deleted, and finding a good example that hasn't would probably get *that* deleted.  Impartial readings of the tooltip seem less common.

Answer (score 1):

> How does a user "improve" a wrong answer? Or an answer that seems to them, given their orientation, wrong?

By posting their own (right) answer.

The fundamental error here is that one should "fix" an answer with which one merely disagrees.

Comment: We agree; but this Q is more about the current wording of the tooltips, and that wording's common but undesired interpretation, (or *mis*interpretation), rather than the correct or best usage of comments and answers.